# Set intersection in MySQL: a clean way

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch entities which satisfy **all n constraints** I give them.

OR operations can be performed by UNION. I wouldnt have asked this question if MySQL supported INTERSECT.

I have entities in the table *subject* and their attributes in *subject_attribute*.

I see the only way for AND operations as **nested queries**:

```
SELECT id
FROM subject_attribute
WHERE attribute = 'des_sen'
AND numerical_value >= 2.0
AND id
IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM subject_attribute
   WHERE attribute = 'tough'
   AND numerical_value >= 3.5
)
```

This means: " fetch entities which satisfy the lowest subquery, then eliminate those who satisfy a higher query" and so on.

---

```
rows(condn x) AND rows(condn y) AND rows(cond z) <--ideal
rows(condn x:rows(cond y:rows(cond z))) <-- I am stuck here
```

I prefer linearly chaining the conditions instead of nesting them as I want to

1. compose queries programatically
2. debug them better

---

**My question:** Given **n individual queries**, how do I AND them cleanly and linearly in MySQL?

Not by using nested queries or stored procedures.

Please note the part about individual queries.

---

**Update**: Jonathan Leffler answered it right. Mark Bannister's answer is much simpler (but I made some bad decisions). Please refer my answer if you are still confused on joins.

Comment: Please can you include table structures in your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each separate query is running against the same table, and that each of them is accessing different values of `attribute`, the simplest way of intersecting all such queries is of the form:

```
SELECT id
FROM subject_attribute
WHERE (attribute = 'des_sen' AND numerical_value >= 2.0) or
      (attribute = 'tough'   AND numerical_value >= 3.5) or
...
group by id
having count(distinct attribute) = N;
```

- where `N` is the number of attribute-numerical_value condition pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't an INNER JOIN (or simply JOIN) the intersection you need?  Assuming you make the join over the relevant common columns.

Hence:

```
SELECT s1.id
  FROM (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'des_sen'
           AND numerical_value >= 2.0
       ) AS s1
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'tough'
          AND numerical_value >= 3.5
       ) AS s2
    ON s1.id = s2.id
```

This extends to N queries (N > 2) cleanly and linearly.

---

> Please explain how you extend it.

```
SELECT s1.id
  FROM (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'des_sen'
           AND numerical_value >= 2.0
       ) AS s1
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'tough'
          AND numerical_value >= 3.5
       ) AS s2
    ON s1.id = s2.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'though'
          AND numerical_value = 14
       ) AS s3
    ON s1.id = s3.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'through'
          AND numerical_value != 45
       ) AS s4
    ON s1.id = s4.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'plough'
          AND numerical_value < 9
       ) AS s5
    ON s1.id = s5.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'cough'
          AND numerical_value < 5
       ) AS s6
    ON s1.id = s6.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'bucolic'
          AND numerical_value >= 3.5
       ) AS s7
    ON s1.id = s7.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'set'
          AND numerical_value BETWEEN 0.23 AND 3.0
       ) AS s8
    ON s1.id = s8.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'intelligent'
          AND numerical_value >= 0.001
       ) AS s9
    ON s1.id = s9.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'anal-retentive'
          AND numerical_value < 7
       ) AS s10
    ON s1.id = s10.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'magnificent'
          AND numerical_value = 35
       ) AS s11
    ON s1.id = s11.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'quantum'
          AND numerical_value >= 55
       ) AS s12
    ON s1.id = s12.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'thoughtfulness'
          AND numerical_value >= 350.237
       ) AS s13
    ON s1.id = s13.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'calamity'
          AND numerical_value = 3.0
       ) AS s14
    ON s1.id = s14.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'pink'
          AND numerical_value > 0.5
       ) AS s15
    ON s1.id = s15.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'cornucopia'
          AND numerical_value BETWEEN 1 AND 12
       ) AS s16
    ON s1.id = s16.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'maudlin'
          AND numerical_value < 3.625
       ) AS s17
    ON s1.id = s17.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'triad'
          AND numerical_value >= 1.723
       ) AS s18
    ON s1.id = s18.id
  JOIN (SELECT id
          FROM subject_attribute
         WHERE attribute = 'ambient'
          AND numerical_value >= 3.1
       ) AS s19
    ON s1.id = s19.id
```

Comment: Please explain how do you extend it

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is confused how to concatenate several queries, here is a simplified representation:

```
SELECT result1.id
FROM (
<query #1>
) AS result1

INNER JOIN (
<query #2>
) AS result2
ON result1.id = result2.id

INNER JOIN (
<query #3>
) AS result3
ON result1.id = result3.id
```

where < query #1> would be

```
SELECT id
FROM subject_attribute
WHERE attribute = 'des_sen'
AND numerical_value >= 2.0
```

---

It's called a self-join, joining a table to itself. Here result1, result2 and result3 are aliases of the same table.

Comment: Only true where the unique key of each result row is held in the same field `id`.

Comment: Mark Bannister, please elaborate

Comment: Aitchnyu, please elaborate on your `<query #n>` queries.